# How to use mod function in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, arithmetic-expressions, modulo

How can we use the mod operation in HQL?

Example of MS-SQL:

```
select * from someTable where someColumn%10 = 1
```

Comment: Is there any explanation about -1?

Answer (score 4):

HQL:

```
FROM someTable WHERE MOD(someColumn,10)=1
```

Of course you may use Binding Parameters for 10 and 1 numbers.

FROM [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html)

*MOD:*

*Calculates the remainder of dividing the first argument by the second.*

Comment: Can this be done for lists too? E.g. if I have a list of values `(21, 64)` and I want to check wether `ANY_TRUE( MOD(col, v) for v in (21, 64) )`